# 2 Users in one model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

New to Django. I'm trying to develop a Feedback module, but designing a database structure makes me confused for various reasons:

- Where do I need to store **feedback_score** (positive/neutral/negative feedback ratio), should it be put in custom User, or somewhere else?
- How should I get the recipient of the feedback credentials, should it be passed by URL, how to link recipient to FeedbackModel in class-based-views?
- How to feedback_score to be calculated each time for every User?

> models.py

```
User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.


class FeedbackModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=False, db_column='id')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=False, related_name='feedback_left_by')
    # recipient = models.ForeignKey(
    #    User,
    #    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    #    primary_key=True)
    FEEDBACK_OPTION = (
        (-1, 'Negative'),
        (0, 'Neutral'),
        (+1, 'Good'),
    )
    feedback = models.IntegerField(choices=FEEDBACK_OPTION)
    opinion = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['left_by', '-id']
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'feedback'
urlpatterns = [
    path('leave_feedback/<str:left_to>/',
         views.leave_feedback.as_view(), name='leavefeedback'),

]
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from .models import FeedbackModel
decorators = [login_required]


@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class leave_feedback(CreateView):
    model = FeedbackModel
    fields = ['feedback', 'opinion']
    success_url = '/'
    #template_name = "feedback/leave_feedback.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.sender = self.request.user
        # ?
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> custom user

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    (...)
    @property
    def feedback_score(self) 
        return ???
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I need to store feedback_score (positive/neutral/negative feedback ratio), should it be put in custom User, or somewhere else?

I think you current Model design is okay with the requirement. Just fix the `ordering` in *class Meta*.
BTW, if you want the user to have only one feedback, then consider using [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField). If you want ratio of Feedback, just do like this:

```
    feedbacks = Feeback.objects.all()
    positive_feedbacks = feedbacks.filter(feedback=1).count()  # returns count of the feedback
    negative_feedbacks = feedbacks.filter(feedback=-1).count()  # returns count of the feedback
    neutral_feedbacks = feedbacks.filter(feedback=0).count()  # returns count of the feedback

    print("Ratio Positive:Negative:Neutral = {}:{}:{}".format(positive_feedbacks/negative_feedbacks, 1, neutral_feedbacks/negative_feedbacks)
```

> How should I get the recipient of the feedback credentials, should it be passed by URL, how to link recipient to FeedbackModel in class-based-views?

You need to make the user login to the system. For example you can follow [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/sll1kw/django-auth-class-based-views-login-and-logout) but there are other good examples out there. Once you login into the system, the user is available via `request.user`. And your current implement reflects this as well.

> How to feedback_score to be calculated each time for every User?

You can get the latest feedback by:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)  # or user = request.user
latest_feedback = user.feedback_left_by.last()
```

Answer (score 0):

feedback_score should be a class method in FeedbackModel, not a field. In general, you do not want fields in your database that can directly be derived from other fields. For instance:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    zodiac_sign = models.CharField()
```

If i have the birth date, I can easily get the zodiac sign. So, zodiac_sign should be a method. The same applies to your case. Just create a method that returns summary information on the feedback.